# Fetching image from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a  MySQL database. I get this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\empinfo.php:13) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\empinfo.php on line 39

```
<?php
header("content_type:" . $row["image_type"]);

?>
<?php echo $info['image']; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: May I ask *why* you are storing the actual image in the database as oppossed to the path? Your code won't work because you are setting the content-type as an image and then using HTML

Comment: Actually: Your error is to do with the fact you are using `header` *after* you have outputted content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php But even with that fixed it won't work

Answer (score 0):

'header' function has to be printed before anything else.

Maybe before the php tag there is some blank space.
You have to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Cannot modify header information

It's not an error. It's warning.

> I'm trying to retrieve an image from a MySQL database

It's Apache/PHP warning. 
You send some output (echo, html, spaces etc.) before calling header...